# Put C# variable as parameter on ASP .NET custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in my ASP page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="genies" Namespace="TheNamespace" Assembly="TheAssembly"%>

...

<% string name = GetTag().Name; %>
<div class="<%= name %>"></div>
<genies:BarGenie ID="BarGenie1" runat="server" Title="<%= name %>" />
```

The BarGenie class has the following code:

```
public class BarGenie : Control {

    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.Write("<div>" + Title + "</div>");
    }

}
```

This is the HTML that is generated:

```
<div class="E00383"></div>
<div><%= name %></div>
```

I'd like to see this HTML:

```
<div class="E00383"></div>
<div>E00383</div>
```

I've tried various things in the ASPX code: @name, <%# name %> etc but I can't figure out what's going on. Is there some other way of inserting a custom control that I should be using? Do I have the wrong approach to using this custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replacing the `<%= %>` tags with `<%# %>` and adding a call to `this.DataBind();` in your codebehind.

Comment: OK, added this.DataBind() as the first line of the Render method. I get a compiler error: The name 'name' does not exist in the current context. It looks like it's complaining about the 'Title="<%# name %>"' parameter...

Answer (score 3):

Try using GetTag().Name instead of name.

Also check out http://www.scottfindlater.co.uk/blog/asp-net-inline-code-and it may help

As in

```
<div class="<%= GetTag().Name%>"></div>
<genies:BarGenie ID="BarGenie1" runat="server" Title="<%= GetTag().Name%>" />
```

Comment: He's calling the variable because he wants to reuse the value in at least two places.

Comment: I made changes suggested by @JoshEarl, then replaced 'name' with 'GetTag().Name' and it's now working fine.

Comment: But I don't get why GetTag().Name works, but name doesn't? So. Weird.

Comment: @Gage, it needs to be Title="<%# GetTag().Name %>" with the <%# at the start (<%= doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

how about setting that value in code-behind:

```
this.BarGenie1.Title = GetTag().Name;
```